# HTML parsing with pup

Tags: command-line, html

I'm trying to parse an HTML page with [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).
This is a command-line HTML parser and it accepts general HTML selectors. I know I can use Python which I do have installed on my machine, but I'd like to learn how to use pup just to get practice with the command-line.

The website I want to scrape from is
https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2018/crime-in-the-u.s.-2018/topic-pages/tables/table-1

I created an html file:

```
curl https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2018/crime-in-the-u.s.-2018/topic-pages/tables/table-1 > fbi2018.html
```

How do I extract out a column of data, such as 'Population'?

This is the command I originally wrote:

```bsh
cat fbi2018.html | grep -A1 'cell31 ' | grep -v 'cell31 ' | sed 's/text-align: right;//' | sed 's/<[/]td>//' | sed 's/--//' | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | sort -nk1,1
```

It actually works but it's an ugly, hacky way to do it, which is why I want to use pup. I noticed that all of the values I need from the column 'Population' have `headers="cell 31 .."` somewhere within the `<td>` tag. For example:

```html
<td id="cell211" class="odd group1 valignmentbottom numbercell" rowspan="1" colspan="1" headers="cell31 cell210">
323,405,935</td>
```

I want to extract all the values that have this particular header in its `<td>` tag, which in this particular example, would be `323,405,935`

It seems that multiple selectors in pup doesn't work, however. So far, I can select all the td elements:

```
cat fbi2018.html | pup 'td'
```

But I don't know how to select headers that contain a particular query.

**EDIT:**
The output should be:

```
272,690,813
281,421,906
285,317,559
287,973,924
290,788,976
293,656,842
296,507,061
299,398,484
301,621,157
304,059,724
307,006,550
309,330,219
311,587,816
313,873,685
316,497,531
318,907,401
320,896,618
323,405,935
325,147,121
327,167,434
```

Comment: Side note, you just can grep it directly without piping it from cat.  `grep -A1 'cell31 ' fbi2018.html`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TLDR

Use this if you want whole column under 'Population' of that table:

```
... | pup 'div#table-data-container:nth-of-type(3) td.group1 text{}'
```

---

## Basic usage

`pup` does support multiple selectors. For example, if you want to grab `wanted text!!` below:

```bsh
$ cat file.html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr class='class-a'>
       <td id='aaa'> some text </td>
       <td id='bbb'> some other text. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='class-b'>
       <td id='aaa'> wanted text!! </td>
       <td id='bbb'> some other text. </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

$ cat file.html | pup 'div table tr.class-b td#aaa'
<td id="aaa">
 wanted text!!
</td>
```

Then add `text{}` to get only the text:

```bsh
$ cat file.html | pup 'div table tr.class-b td#aaa text{}'
 wanted text!!
```

So in your case it should be:

```bsh
$ cat fbi2018.html | pup 'td#cell211 text{}'

323,405,935
```

Or better, you don't have to download the page, just pipe `curl` to `pup`

```bsh
url="https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2018/crime-in-the-u.s.-2018/topic-pages/tables/table-1"
curl -s "$url" | pup 'td#cell211 text{}'
```

---

## Explanation

If you want values from an entire column, then you should know the characteristic of the element you wanted to scrape.

In this case 'Population' column from given link. On the page, there's 2 tables wrapped in `<div id='table-data-container'>...` If you use  `... | pup 'div#table-data-container'`, it will also grab data from the second table. You don't want that.

[image: tables]

How do `pup` know you want the first table? Well, there's another hint. As you can see, there's few `<div>`s. And your table is on 3rd div. So you can use [CSS's psuedo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), in this case `div#table-data-container:nth-of-type(3)`

Then, the column has unique selector as `td.group1`

[image: selector]

Combine them all then pipe it to `grep -v -e '^$'` to get rid of blank spaces.

```
... | pup 'div#table-data-container:nth-of-type(3) td.group1 text{}' | grep -v -e '^$'
```

and you will get what you wanted:

```
272,690,813
281,421,906
285,317,559
...
327,167,434
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know how to extract a value out of one particular cell, how do I do that for the entire column under "Population"? Of course, I could do `pup 'td#cell41 text{}'`, `pup 'td#cell51 text{}'`, `pup 'td#cell51 text{}'`, ... `pup 'td#cell221 text{}'`,  `pup 'td#cell231 text{}'` But I'd like to find a simpler way?

Comment: P.S. There are 20 cells in total under that column.

Comment: @rplee And kindly accept my answer if this does solve your problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Answer accepted :)

Comment: Ok, I played around with this a little more. And I was able to get the data from the other columns as well, by just incrementing the group number (ie. `... | pup 'div#table-data-container:nth-of-type(3) td.group21 text{}' | grep -v -e '^$` for the column for 'Motor Vehicle Theft'.) However, how did you know 'Population' column was in the 3rd division? I tried to get the data under the 'Year' column, but I couldn't. I can see that 'Year' column is in group0, but it's not in the 3rd division because nothing prints out when I use that same pup command for group0. How do I get the 'Year' column?

Comment: @rplee The 'Year' column is not `td` but `th`. Use `th.group0` selector, you'll get year data. You might need to filter out some unwanted values though.

Comment: It's not that 'Population' column which is on 3rd div, but the whole table is. If you don't specify it, it will also grab data from the second table of the page. Try it yourself

Comment: Oh I see now, `th.group0` works, but I just need to filter out the superscript numbers 5 and 6. I did try not specifying the division 3, and saw that it got the values from the corresponding column on Table 1A also. But how did you know that the whole table is in the 3rd div?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108708/discussion-between-annahri-and-rplee).

Comment: One last question about this discussion... Can I get two columns with a single pup command, as in does pup allow for ranges to be selected?

Comment: @rplee AFAIK, yes you can. Just use commas in the selectors. Haven't tried it myself but It's in the documentation.

Comment: Ah ok, the closest I got was: `curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2018/crime-in-the-u.s.-2018/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup 'div#table-data-container:nth-of-type(3) td.group2, td.group4 text{}' | grep -v -e '^$' ` which prints a single column of values from group2 and group4 but also includes some values from Table 1A which I obviously don't want. I also would like 2 columns of data. Not a big deal though, I just did pup to extract each column individually and put each of the columns into separate text files then paste them together.

Comment: But it's nice to know for the future that pup has that capability

Comment: Please do not extend commend section. Use chat instead via above link. I reply there

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:
1) Parse the values from an HTML table
2) Do your desired operations (min, max, ect)

I don't think you will be able to do this in one line. 
I like the idea of converting the HTML table to a .csv and then operating on the CSV. You can use AWK for that but I'd use the Python library, Pandas, instead. Why write bash if you can avoid it?

I found a way to use bash to convert an HTML table to a .csv [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403087/how-can-i-convert-an-html-table-to-csv)

An example of using AWK to average a column is [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/39982-use-awk-calculate-average-column-3-a.html)

Comment: That's why OP is using `pup`. Just like `jq` but for HTML.

Comment: The question has been changed a few times since I answered it. Originally pup and jq were in the question title but not explicitly required for the question. Since the question changed, I would have deleted my answer if I could have. Thanks for your answer. I learned something new.